# Convert a list of digits and letters (scanf) turned into a single INT number

Tags: c, algorithm

This part is only a small piece in my program, but hopefully I'll manage with the rest on my own.

The code should pretty much play with different bases of numbers, so let's cut right in the middle and assume we have `int base`.

That base can be anywhere from 2 (binary) to 36.
The number you read can't be integer, because the user may include letters in it, and when I say letters, I mean `{a=10, b, c, d, ..., z}` (z is 35), in this case, the user can decide on a base greater than 9, with digits greater than 10, that will result in a mixed input, for example `24e1`. 
This is why I need to read this number digit by digit, and turn it into a decimal number (a normal, base 10 number).
In order to do that, it is no surprise that for `24e1` I should do:  `2*base^3+4*base^2+15*base^1+1*base^0` (e=15 as I mentioned above).

**The problem is that you are NOT allowed to use any library besides `stdio.h`, and you are NOT allowed to use Arrays or strings.**

I already wrote a function for power, so you can skip this part and just type ^ and I'll transform it, but I am completely lost as for the rest. How am I supposed to do the above?
How can I tell how many digits there will be.. I should probably count the input somehow or something.. because like in our example, the first digit got power of 3, and we only knew that because we already know the number has 4 digits. In that program I won't be able to tell ahead.
Also, how can I turn that back into the given base? Before I play with the number, I turn it into a decimal number, do w/e I want with it, and then return it to the desired base. I know how to do it manually, but how can I do it in the code, where letters may be involved? I need to print the digits once again, but I don't know how..

so far:

```
//read until user input is Enter:
    while (num != '\n') { 
        num = getchar();
//because we don't want to be calculating the value of enter:
        if (num == '\n') {
            break; 
        }
//we can assume user input will be numbers or letters in the rightful base
        if (num >= '1' && num <= '9') { 
            // -'0' in order to get the actual number:
            num = num-'0';
            }
        else { 
            // subtract value of W so we start from a=10:
            num = num-'W';
        }
            //THIS LINE should be something that will help me convert num to base 10
```

In the program I should basically get 2 numbers in a certain base, do the mathematical: num1+num1, and output the result IN THE SAME BASE GIVEN BY THE USER.

for example, if user input was `base = 10`
numbers:
`132,
24`

output should be `156`

If user input was `base = 20`
numbers:
`10,
g`
OUTPUT:
`1g`

If user input is `base = 36`
numbers:
`zzz,
1`
OUTPUT:
`1000`

This is why I need to first convert it to base 10, so I will be able to do the math there, and then convert it back to the given base and output digit by digit.
The problem is that I have no clue how to do that with base greater than 10.

for base 10 (only digits) and lower I can pretty much do the following:

```
numAsInt = 0;
while (num != '\n') { 
        num = getchar();
        if (num == '\n') {
            break; 
        }
        numAsInt = (numAsInt+(num-'0'))*10;
}
numAsInt = NumAsInt/10;
```

so basically if user input is 123, base 10 (it does the following:

```
numAsInt = (1)*10; // numAsInt==10
numAsInt = (12)*10; //numAsInt==120
numAsInt = (123)*10; //numAsInt==1230
numAsInt = 1230/10 //numAsInt==123
```

This way I don't have to know the power of the digits, because I don't care how long the input (num) is, but I can't do the same when it comes to numbers with letters..

Comment: Actually, you should do: `result = ((2 * base + 4) * base + 15) * base + 1;`, or iteratively: `result = 0; result = result * base + 2; result = result * base + 4; result = result * base + 15; result = result * base + 1;`, except that you write that as a loop, not as consecutive assignments. No need for a power function like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an simple way to do it, In some text it is called as Horner's rule for polynomial.

Algorithm:-

```
0. Set acc = 0

1. Read a character say ch

2. acc = acc*base + value(ch)

3. do 1,2 till end of input.
```

[Horners Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)

**Edit:-** Following is C program to solve your problem:-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int valueof(char ch) {


 if(ch>='0'&&ch<='9') {

   return(ch-'0');
 }

 else {

  return(10+ch-'a');

 }

}


char toChar(int i) {

   if(i<10)
     return('0' + i);
   return('a'+i-10);
}

int convert(int base) {

   int acc = 0;
   char ch;
   while((ch=getchar())!='\n') {

       acc = acc*base + valueof(ch);
   }    

   return(acc);
}

void print_base(int base,int num) {
  int k;

  if(num>0) {
     k= toChar(num%base);    
     print_base(base,num/base);
     printf("%c",k);
  }

}



int main() {

  int base,num1,num2,sum;
  printf("Enter the base: ");
  scanf("%d",&base);
  getchar();
  printf("Enter num1: ");
  num1 = convert(base);
  printf("Enter num2: ");
  num2 = convert(base);
  printf("Sum: ");
  sum = num1 + num2;
  print_base(base,sum);


}
```

Comment: Thanks!

I don't get one thing though.. you pretty much say that I don't need to convert the numbers to base 10 and I can store them as they are, 
but then how will I be able to output them the way I want to? Please read my edit to the original post, I tried to be more clear and I added a lot of info (I believe)

Comment: @user2997196 when you do the above steps then you convert the number into base 10 and if you want to add two number then do above steps on both numbers and the result will be num1+num2 and then you reconvert it to base given by user by dividing sum by base successively like we do to convert decimal to binary

Comment: Ohhh I understood what you guys are saying. What I said is possible to do for any base equal or lower than 10 (multiplication by 10 etc) is basically the same for every base when multiplying by that same base, and it's the same like doing the power method, only in that case we do not need to know the length of the number

Thanks a lot for the solution, it helped me with a couple other functions I had troubles with (like the recursive one)! and I finished the rest as well.

Comment: I used `'W'+i` (or `ch-'W'`) instead of your `'a'+i-10` (or `ch-'a'+10`) though, because it seems easier to read and it's basically the same, because `W` is 87 in ASCII value compared to `a` which is 97

Thanks a bunch Again!

Answer (score 1):

Actually your z shall have a value of 35 and not 36.

```
Regarding your problem, I suggest you do the following:  
1. Initialize SUM = 0.  
2. Read next character.  
3. SUM = SUM*base + value of character.
```

Repeat Steps 2 and 3 until all characters are read. This way even if you do not know from the beginning the number of characters, the SUM shall automatically come to the value of the number read.

This way, you shall be able to get the value of both numbers in **base 10** variables SUM1 and SUM2.

Add them using simple + operator and compute SUM in base 10.
Then keep dividing by the base and outputting the quotient values to screen after converting them to the respective base characters.

The remainder shall be the last digit that you output.

Comment: If you initialize the SUM to zero, you don't need to give a special case treatment to the first character (and special cases are bad news).

Comment: @Abhinshek

Thanks!

I don't get one thing though.. you pretty much say that I don't need to convert the numbers to base 10 and I can store them as they are, 
but then how will I be able to output them the way I want to? Please read my edit to the original post, I tried to be more clear and I added a lot of info (I believe)

Comment: Thank you as well! as I stated above, I understand what you guys are saying, that's basically the same like the power method

Sorry for not being able to rank you guys up, I'm still a newb D: